# SignalR Not Working in IIS but Working in Localhost

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, asp.net-core, signalr

I connect an api and 2 clients with signalR on localhost and get notifications. When I throw the API to the IIS server, SignalR Hub does not connect, but my post and get methods in the Controller work.

Client:

```
@section Scripts{
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(() => {
        var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
                .withUrl("http://myDomain/denemehub")
                .withAutomaticReconnect()
                .build();
        $("#constatus").text(connection.state);
        connection.start().then(() => {
            $("#constatus").text(connection.state);
            connection.invoke("DenemeAddedMessageAsync");
        }).catch((err) => { console.log(err) });

        connection.on("receiveProductAddedMessage", (value) => {
            $("#denemevalue").text(value);
        });
    });
</script>
}
```

Program.cs in API

```
builder.Services.AddCors(opt =>
{
    opt.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", builder =>
    {
        builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
        .AllowAnyMethod()
        .AllowAnyHeader();
    });
});

app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");

app.MapHub<DenemeHub>("/denemehub");
```

Errors appearing in the Console screen:

Failed to load resource: net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
Warning: Error from HTTP request. TypeError: Failed to fetch.
Error: Failed to complete negotiation with the server: TypeError: Failed to fetch
Error: Failed to start the connection: Error: Failed to complete negotiation with the server: TypeError: Failed to fetch

Add Web.config

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
        </modules>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Cors With Origin("http://localhost:5171").AllowCredential()

```
builder.Services.AddCors(opt =>
{
    opt.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", builder =>
    {
        builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:5171")
        .AllowAnyMethod()
        .AllowAnyHeader()
        .AllowCredentials();
    });
});
```

IIS websocket protocol is enabled.

Comment: `ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR` means your server is not configured correctly (at least as far as your browser believes), most commonly with your certificate.  You've provided no information about that.

Comment: There is no ssl certificate on our IIS server, we connect via 'http' url. When I try skipNegotiation: true, I get a connection closed error.

Comment: "we connect via 'http' url".  That may be what you think you're doing, but your browser clearly doesn't.

Comment: but we can access other api, web applications in IIS via http with the same browser. It is strange that the problem is only in SignalR and we could not find a solution.

Comment: I know you asked about IIS. I'd like to share an issue I came across while working with .NET 8, hoping it might be helpful. I attempted to perform a URL lowercase operation using RewriteOptions. I encountered an error related to negotiation. Despite some research, I couldn't find a solution. Eventually, I discovered the issue was linked to the Rewrite module. There might be something similar hindering its proper functionality.

Comment: Try commenting this line of code.  `//app.UseHttpsRedirection();`.

Comment: And you also need to enable front-end logging feature, like  `signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl(Url).configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Debug) .withAutomaticReconnect().build();`

Answer (score 0):

i changed the

> app.MapHub("/denemehub");

to

> app.MapHub("/deneme");

and add web.config

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
        </modules>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

problem fixed. but i dont know why.